# Remove text from textarea then pressing enter key

Tags: jquery, scroll, textarea, chat

I wrote a code that sends a message and scrolls down then the user presses the "Enter" key. You can see it down below:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (e.which == 13 && target.is('#message')) {
      message = $('#message').val();
      if (message && /\S/.test(message)) {
        $.post('/users/send', {
          roomId: room.id,
          message: message
        }).done(function (res) {
          var response = JSON.parse(res);
          var lastmsg = JSON.parse(response.messages[response.messages.length - 1]);
          var lastmsgDate = new Date(lastmsg.date);
          if ('{{user.imgUrl}}') {
            $('#messages').append('<div class="container"><div class="my-message"><p>' + message + '</p><small class="date">' +
              lastmsgDate.getHours() + ':' + lastmsgDate.getMinutes() + '</small><img src="' + lastmsg.img + '" alt="avatar"></div></div>');
          } else {
            $('#messages').append('<div class="container"><div class="my-message"><p>' + message + '</p><small class="date">' +
            lastmsgDate.getHours() + ':' + lastmsgDate.getMinutes() + '</small></div></div>');
          }
        });
        var height = $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('#messages').scrollTop(height);
        $('#message').val('');
      }
    }
  });
```

I thought that it should work correctly, but \n staying in the textarea. Also, it wont to scroll down. What should I do?

*sorry for my bad code*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: when you hit enter, your function runs and do what  it needs to do, then it continues with the default behavior of the event (key pressed 'Enter'), so it jumps a line. (it wasn't letting the "\n" it was beign created before your function ran)

What I did is: just after the `if` statement that check if is enter and the target is correct, calls the `preventDefault()` this will prevent the line to be jumped by the enter key. Also, call `.focus()` to be sure that the focus is in the textarea and now in the beggining.

```js
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (e.which == 13 && target.is('#message')) {
        e.preventDefault()
        message = $('#message').val();
        if (message && /\S/.test(message)) {  
            //ADD your logic and call here
            //...
            $('#message').val('');                        
            $('#message').focus();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

(I removed your AJAX post call to be able to create a working snippet here.)